Blend Mean Radius for Skin modifier
I'm working with the skin modifier. I have a line were the mean radius is 2 on one end and 0.3 on the other. Is there an easy way to make the points in between have a progression from one radius to the other?

Or should I do the deformation with a lattice and make the geometry follow a curve to get the same result?
